# How to get rid of lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit warning message?

Tags: boot, kernel, lvm

Is there way to avoid this message during the first boot stage ?
It comes right before the lvm passphrase prompt and then again after passphrase is entered too.

```
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is activated in the /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and lvm just do that it allways do and try first to use it.

```
 #LVM uses built-in clustered locking with clvmd.
 #This is incompatible with lvmetad. If **use_lvmetad** is enabled,
 #LVM prints a warning and disables lvmetad use.
```

< Blacker47> lvmetad is a ~caching-deamon for the metadata, so for every rescan (done if you creates new lv, new snapshot, activates new lv and many more) there is no need to access drives again and again. may have much more usecases. for me it helps not to spinup disks in standby if i activate my backup lv.

On the boot the daemon not running, so it has to work without with the fallback. the warning at the boot is just for ignore. it would be only interesting if you get such warning later and not on boot.

If I would like to do not use lvmetad I should set this in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf

```
use_lvmetad 0
```

and then update all initramfs images with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```